# Execute wkhtmltopdf from PHP

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, html2pdf

I have this working fine from Linux command line:

> wkhtmltopdf entry.html output.pdf

But the following doesn't work from PHP code:

exec ('wkhtmltopdf entry.html output.pdf');

Interesting, I've googled and a lot of non-checked solutions and with no explanation why this is a problem.
Thanks if you have the good ones.

Comment: You may need to specify an absolute path to the executable, e.g. `exec(/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf ...)`, if the sub-shell invoked by PHP ends up having a different PATH setting than your standard default shell. As well, if you're doing the exec from within a web-based script, then permissions are going to be a factor as well.

Comment: Do you get any PHP error messages? What happens when you type that directly into the shell?

Comment: check the apache error log, probably you will find the answer there ( like me )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wkhtmltopdf has [bindings](https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf-bindings), one of them is for PHP. You could give those a shot.

Comment: interesting, just browsed it. HOWEVER, the command is the most handy for me because I want to make the conversion on the fly. And then, why the exec call is not executed?

Answer (score 10):

had the same problem and i don't think anyone else should waste > 3 hours:

the solution is here: [wkhtmltopdf error in apache log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483673/wkhtmltopdf-error-in-apache-log?rq=1)

you just have to install xvfp "to emulate a x-environment"

```
exec("xvfb-run -a wkhtmltopdf test.html output.pdf")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a PHP wrapper around wkhtmltopdf 
http://mikehaertl.github.com/phpwkhtmltopdf/
Very simple

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `wkhtmltopdf` is not in the PATH variable for www-data.

```
whereis wkhtmltopdf
```

will tell you where the binary is located; Binaries usually resides in `/usr/bin/...` on *nix machines. Then replace `wkhtmltopdf` with *e.g.* `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf` in your command like this.

```
/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf entry.html output.pdf
```

Comment: `type -P 'wkhtmltopdf'` is more reliable than `whereis`.

Comment: I've also tried this:$input = getcwd() . "/entry.html";
 $output = getcwd() . "/output.pdf";
 exec ('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf $entry $output'); but same result.

Comment: @user238831, then try `getcwd()` ([function.getcwd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)) to verify that the script is executing in the correct directory. -- Look at what `getcwd()` returns.

Comment: @Alix Axel -- Please elaborate, or provide sources.

Comment: @user238831 -- Yes, did you look at what `getcwd()` said? Are you in the right directory?

Comment: @jwandborg: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command/10529#10529

Comment: Also, try specifying the full path of the files. E.g., `exec("/usr/local/bin/wkhtml2pdf /tmp/whatever.html /var/www/output/output.pdf");`

Comment: @Will Martin - yes, see above.

Comment: @Alix Axel -- That looks correct, as long as `whereis` and `which` are the same deal.

Comment: @jwandborg - I've used getcwd() in the code above, all paths are secure

Comment: @Alix Axel -- there's no other code than that ... I've put in comments all program to fix this one line problem.

Comment: @user238831 -- Have you verified that both of the files exist at runtime? A tip is to print the output of the command, there's some details about it over at http://php.net/function.exec#refsect1-function.exec-returnvalues

Comment: @jwandborg -- I've checked to have the input file. I don't get anything in output since the exec() statement is not executed

Comment: @user238831 -- Of course the `exec` statement is executed, if you haven't commented it out. Use `$output = passthru('/usr/local/bin/wkhtml2pdf /tmp/foo.html /bar/foo.pdf'); echo $output;` so that you can see if the command line execution of `wkhtml2pdf` complains about anythin.

Comment: @jwandborg - Many thanks for your time. It still doesn't work, I've done all the scenarios, replayed some of them already mentioned in other postings on SO, but no positive issue. It is a three line PHP that can be tested a proposal. For some reason "reason" doesn't play here. Very frustrating ...

Answer (score 2):

Just had this problem - simple solution in my case: I didn't realise that PHP was in Safe Mode.  Switched off Safe Mode and it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem.

My solution on a `Windows 2008 R2` server with `PHP 5.4`:

```
exec('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite\subdir\wkhtmltopdf input.html output.pdf');
```

AND this was it (After > 5 hours searching the net including this) a new file called output.txt, renamed it to output.pdf and give the user 'everybody' rights to it.

These are my tryouts:

```
  exec(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite\wkhtmltopdf );
  echo(exec(wkhtmltopdf.exe cache.html output.pdf));
  exec("xvfb-run -a wkhtmltopdf test.html output.pdf")
  $execute = "xvfb-run -a wkhtmltopdf cache.html output.pdf";
  $out = shell_exec("/path/to/wkhtmlto­pdf --version"); echo($out); 
  $out = passthru('/usr/local/bin/wkhtml2pdf
```

Hope these are usefull to others